# Suppress Columns with Null Values in Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, pivot-table

Hey guys the following query basically combines 3 tables in a pivot table to display the StaffReference Code, StaffCode as headers and WipAmount in between.  This code is basically finished as it runs correctly, however I want to suppress any columns that have all fields NULL.  This will make it easier for reading the report

example of what the current output is

```
--------ejh -----aea-----fum       
ejh----null----10.00----6.00
fum---null-----5.00-----null
aea---null-----null-----7.00
```

example of what I need:

```
-------aea-----fum       
ejh--10.00----6.00
fum---5.00----null
aea---null-----7.00
```

Basically, if a column is full of NULL values, omit that column the query I have is the following.  This query works and displays all the correct data

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @columns TABLE (COL varchar(50))
declare @columnscsv varchar(MAX)

insert into @columns
select distinct StaffCode from tblStaff

select @columnscsv = COALESCE(@columnscsv + '],[','') + COL from @columns
set @columnscsv = '[' + @columnscsv + ']'

SET @sql = 'Select StaffReference ' + @columnscsv + ' 
FROM(SELECT ocr.staffcode, em.StaffReference, WipAmount FROM tblTranWip w
Join tblengagement e on e.contindex = w.contindex
Join tblstaff ocr on ocr.staffindex = e.clientpartner
Join tblstaff em on em.staffindex = e.clientmanager
WHERE (w.WIPDate>={ts ''2013-04-01 00:00:00''} 
AND w.WIPDate<{ts ''2014-03-31 00:00:01''}) 
AND w.TransTypeIndex=1 AND w.ContIndex<900000
) as a 
PIVOT (SUM(WipAmount) for StaffCode in (' + @columnscsv + ')) AS PVT 
Order by StaffReference'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: can you put a sample table with some rows so that the queries can be tested ?

Comment: Yes I will add a sample table tonight. Sorry I been out of town and haven't been able to check back. Any ideas yet?

Answer (score 1):

You could use isnull to get rid of the null values and just specify whatever you want instead. Below I just use a blank space but you could return 0 for any numerical values.

```
SELECT ISNULL(ocr.staffcode, ''), isnull(em.StaffReference, ''), isnull(WipAmount, '') FROM tblTranWip
```

**EDITED for requested clarification -- see comments below**

So the `ISNULL` will allow you to get rid of null values but it replaces those values.

I'm going to explain what the code you are using is doing. First you are using dynamic SQL and while this is useful can have some security implications. Tthis link][1](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) is one of my favorite explanations of the curse and blessings of dynamic SQL. It's definitely good to read if you haven't used it before.

This code is taking the columns that you have identified in a table and is stuffing it into a string that is comma delimited, which will be used in your select statement later.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @columns TABLE (COL varchar(50))
declare @columnscsv varchar(MAX)

insert into @columns
select distinct StaffCode from tblStaff

select @columnscsv = COALESCE(@columnscsv + '],[','') + COL from @columns
set @columnscsv = '[' + @columnscsv + ']'
```

This line here is what is setting your columns. When you use the Pivot function you must specify the columns you want to pivot on and by using dynamic SQL here you are allowing them to be variable:

```
SET @sql = 'Select StaffReference ' + @columnscsv + '
```

However what I'm noticing is because you have those values statically set before you even run your inner query which I'll list out here, that is constraining you to use all of those column names regardless if they return null:

```
SELECT ocr.staffcode, em.StaffReference, WipAmount FROM tblTranWip w
Join tblengagement e on e.contindex = w.contindex
Join tblstaff ocr on ocr.staffindex = e.clientpartner
Join tblstaff em on em.staffindex = e.clientmanager
WHERE (w.WIPDate>={ts ''2013-04-01 00:00:00''} 
AND w.WIPDate<{ts ''2014-03-31 00:00:01''}) 
AND w.TransTypeIndex=1 AND w.ContIndex<900000
```

So, it follows that if you truly want to exclude the null columns, then you want to be able to populate the `@columns` table dynamically with only the columns that would hold values, which you should be able to identify using your initial inner query that I have pasted above this. If you aren't getting your column values from that inner statement then we need more information in order to understand where those are coming from.

Comment: I'm going to test this tonight. I don't really want to display anything such as zeros. I want to basically get rid of any columns that are all null down the column. That way the person reading the report doesn't have to scroll horizontally forever to see the columns that do have meaningful data.

Comment: ok so I didn't see that sample output the first time. this solution only gets rid of the null values it doesn't actually suppress an entire column of null values. so first, if you are creating your columns dynamically already you may want to check if those columns have any values to begin with before you create them. second, did you look to see if you had any null rows from your innermost query because that would be where you can see that you are getting null columns. if you do have rows with null values for the amount you can use a having clause to filter those out.'

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Where in the code would I have to check for the Null value. I created this query from reading everywhere online how to create the pivot table, but don't fully understand how the code works outside of the select statement and pivot.

Comment: ok, i'm going to edit my answer to give you a more detailed (and better formatted) explanation.

Comment: I am getting my values with the inner statement.  This inner statement shows it in non-pivot view. These columns are the OCR, EM, and and wipamount. What I am still struggling to understand is why part of the statement or whole query I have to alter to remove the null columns.  Sorry I am much more of a visual learner hah!

Comment: yes i understand that the inner shows the statement in non-pivot view. but try left joining the `@columns` table with your inner statement and have that column show up. you should see what i mean by having blank rows. otherwise the best way to be able to help you is if you create a sqlfiddle with sample data. (http://sqlfiddle.com/)